# How to use CTensor for the Maxwell stress tensor F?

Tags: xact

I have used the `CTensor` to compute an equation of motion. Everything is ok but the stress tensor F. How can I rewrite this tensor using CTensor. The needed definitions are as follows:

```
DefManifold[M, 6, {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Sigma], \[Delta], \[Iota], \
\[Mu], \[Omicron], \[FinalSigma], \[Tau], \[Upsilon], \[Chi], \
\[Omega], \[Nu], \[Rho], \[Gamma]}]

DefChart[\[ScriptCapitalB], M, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {t[], 
r[], \[Eta]1[], \[Zeta]1[], \[Eta]2[], \[Zeta]2[]}, 
ChartColor -> Blue]

MakeRule[{F[-\[Alpha], -\[Beta]], 
CD[-\[Alpha]]@A[-\[Beta]] - CD[-\[Beta]]@A[-\[Alpha]]}]
```

and `A(r)` is

```
A = {h[r[]], 0, 0, 2 h[r[]] m \[Eta]1[], 0, 2 h[r[]] m \[Eta]2[]}.
```

I am ready to add any information if needed. Thanks.

Comment: Have you defined a metric?  I'm pretty sure that xAct & xCoba need one to do coordinate calculations involving `CD`.  Also, I believe that you'll need to invoke `DefScalarFunction[h]` to let xCoba know that `h` is a scalar function of your coordinates, and it's probably good practice to invoke `DefConstantSymbol[m]` as well (assuming it is in fact a constant.)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be the answer.

```
AA0 = {h[r[]], 0, 0, 2 h[r[]] m \[Eta]1[], 0, 2 h[r[]] m \[Eta]2[]};

AA = CTensor[AA0, {-\[ScriptCapitalB]}];

FF1 = (CD[-\[Alpha]]@AA[-\[Beta]] - CD[-\[Beta]]@AA[-\[Alpha]])[[0, 
1]]
```

Comment: Your code in the original question is in 6-D, but your vector here is 8-D.  Did you mean to include the `\[Eta]3[]` part?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I correct it. Thanx.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Note also that you'll need to specify a metric before you can actually calculate anything using xCoba — see my comment on your original question.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, of course for final calculation a metric will be needed.